# select text from Jlist component

Tags: java, swing, selection, jlist, jtextpane

I have a Jlist that component is JTextpane that contains String such as "hello world"
I want to select word "hello" by selecting Jlist component
How can I know which word is selected, "hello" or "world" 
I use method Jtextpane.getSelection() but it doesn't work 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any sample code??

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that you are creating `JTextPane`s as the components in your list cell renderer. The problem here is that the components that are returned by the cell renderer are used only for painting the cells content, no actual functionality of the component is available.

A solution would be to not use a `JList` but instead using a big `JTextPane` with HTML content.